Why do I need to add 'const' in the custom comparator?
I am not very familiar with C++, and am confused about how a comparator works.
The below code is how I can find the position I want to insert a new interval:
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> intervals; // = ...
    vector<int> newInterval;       // = ...
    // ...

    auto comp = [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) { return a[0] < b[0]; };
    auto it = upper_bound(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), newInterval, comp);
}

Hen I try to remove const, it will get a compile error.
Why do I need to add const for this custom comparator?

Because comparator should not modify what it compares, that would make comparing things impossible.

Note that a const member function can be called on both a non-const and a const object. But a non-const member function can be called on only a const object. Good c++ book

A side note: If you are learning C++, you should unlearn using namespace std;. See: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

std::upper_bound is defined to take const T& value as its third parameter. And it passes that value to the comparator. So the comparator has to accept a const object at least for its first parameter.

The proposed duplicate talks about why operator() of a custom comparator must be a const member function. But that's not the const this question is asking about. (operator() of a lambda is const by default, unless the lambda is marked mutable).

Always post complete error along with your question. Also this is not a [mcve]

@IgorTandetnik Another dupe: Why is a lambda's call-operator implicitly const?

Demo to show that one const, on the first parameter, is sufficient to get the code to compile (not that it's a good idea). That's because std::upper_bound always calls the comparator as comp(value, *it) where value is its third parameter and it is some iterator in the range; and value is taken by const reference.

@user12002570 The OP appears to ask why lambda's parameters must be const; why auto comp = [](vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b) { return a[0] < b[0]; }; doesn't work. At least, that's how I understood the question. They say "I tried removing const", and those are the only instances of const explicitly present in the code shown.

@IgorTandetnik interestignly, the documentation states regarding comp that "While the signature does not need to have const &, the function must not modify the objects passed to it and must be able to accept all values of type (possibly const) Type1 and Type2 regardless of value category". I wonder how can this be achieved without a const& ?

@Yksisarvinen thanks meanwhile I understood this (see in my answer).

Is the motivation for this question the fact that, in many places, if const X is acceptable (e.g., as a function argument) then X is as well?

Why do I need to add 'const' in the custom comparator?  Because its too late to change the language to make const the implicit default, and require mutable to designate a non-const reference parameter.

Sure! Thanks @wohlstad for your clear answer :)

@Yuan happy to help. BTW Just in case you are not aware: you can also upvote the answer, voting and accepting is separate. See: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

From the std::upper_bound documentation regarding the comparator (comp):

The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the
following:
bool pred(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
While the signature does not need to have const &, the function must
not modify the objects passed to it and must be able to accept all
values of type (possibly const).
(thus, Type1 & is not allowed, nor is Type1 unless for Type1 a move is equivalent to a copy(since C++11))

(emphasis is mine)
Since the comparator must be able to accept const values (and must not modify them), the trivial solution is to use const &. The other alternative is to accept the objects by value, which is relevant only for simple types like int.
Note:
As @IgorTandetnik commented in practice only the first object must be const, in all 3 major compilers (gcc, clang, MSVC) - see demo. But this is true only in the case that non-const iterators are used (like in the code you posted). If you use const iterators (cbegin(), cend()) both objects in the comparators must be const in order to compile.
In any case it's good practice to have a const & for both objects in the comparator.

The reason why the second parameter could be non-const-ref is because non-const iterators are passed. If you use c-prefixed functions or make v itself constant, e.g. std::upper_bound(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 0, comp), the code won't compile.

@Evg - good point. Added a clarification to the note.
